# Is it possible to use AngularJS as alternative to pdf creators?

Tags: angularjs, pdf

I am newbie in AngularJS . I have used `itextsharp` and `pdf sharp` to create and download pdf. I like to use AngularJS instead of these two pdf creator kits.

Comment: Have you seen this https://github.com/sayanee/angularjs-pdf

Answer (score 1):

Refer this below link to create a pdf using angularjs.

https://medium.com/@darilldrems/angularjs-export-html-table-to-pdf-excel-or-doc-formats-bb741d06dfec